# Powershell: Convert Get-ADGroupMember output to correct type for Add-MailboxFolderPermission -User parameter

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server-2007

I have been tasked with writing a short Powershell script for work where I take a group of mailboxes and modify permissions for a list of users who are all part of one group. I use Get-ADGroupMember to get my list of users and store it in an array and then pass that array to the Add-MailboxFolderPermission cmdlet. However upon running the script I receive the following error for each user in the array:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on paramter 'User'. Cannot convert the "@<Name="somename">" value of type "Deserialized.Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPrincipal" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.MailboxFolderUserIDParameter"
```

Which I take to mean "Sorry incompatible types". Does anyone have any tips on how I can transform the objects returned from the first cmdlet to be passed to the second cmdlet? This is the first bit of powershell that I've had to write...I will continue reading in the meantime. Thanks for any response. Below is my code.

```
#Prepare to connect to exchange server
. "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1"

#Connect to local exchange server
Connect-ExchangeServer -auto

$rooms = @("box1",
"box2",
"box3",
"box4",
"box5")


$users = @(Get-ADGroupMember somegroup| Select Name)


foreach ($room in $rooms) {

   foreach ($user in $users) {

       Add-MailBoxFolderPermission -Identity $room`:\calendar -User $user -AccessRights Author

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the help on Add-MailboxFolderPermssion give this description for the User parameter:

The User parameter specifies who's granted permission to view or modify the folder contents of the user specified in the Identity parameter. The following values are acceptable:

• Alias
• SMTP address

If the email alias matches the user name, then you can use that.

```
$users = @(Get-ADGroupMember somegroup| Select -Expand Name)
```

If it's possible they might not match, it's safer to resolve it by DN:

```
$users = @(Get-ADGroupMember somegroup | 
             Select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName |
             Get-Recipient | select -ExpandProperty Alias)
```

Or you can Select the PrimarySmtpAddress if you want to use that.